# How to save value in variable in jmeter?

Tags: random, jmeter

Lets say my input field is below format:

${__Random(1,28,)}/${__Random(1,12,)}/${__Random(1970,2000,)

I want to reuse the above generated value, how may I save it in variable?

Answer (score 1):

Add the expression as the value of [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) Pre-Processor

If the name is e.g. `birthDay` use it later as `${birthDay}` or in script as `vars.get("birthDay")`

> Values can be accessed in any test component in the same thread group, using the function syntax: ${variable}.

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. [__changeCase() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__changeCase) which will not do anything in your case, however it has possibility to evaluate nested [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and save the result into a new JMeter Variable

The relevant syntax would be:

```
${__changeCase(${__Random(1,28,)}/${__Random(1,12,)}/${__Random(1970,2000,)},,myVariable)}
```

Demo:

[image]

`__changeCase()` function is available since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)